How to exclude a directory from Intellij IDEA class search results?
On intellij IDEA, whenever I try to search for a class that starts with E, I get these results that freeze the search tool for some time. Of course this is not the class I am searching, I am searching for a Java class.
So how to exclude this directory from class search results (since class search has no regex filter like the "Search text everywhere" tool)?


which version are you using?

You can mark the directory as excluded by opening the Project tool window (Alt+1), right-clicking on the directory and selecting Mark Directory As > Excluded. All files in the directory will then be excluded from navigation/searching. From the documentation:

Files in excluded folders are ignored by code completion, navigation and inspection. That is why when you exclude a folder that you don't need at the moment, you can increase the IDE performance. Normally, compilation output folders are marked as excluded.
Apart from excluding the entire folders, you can also exclude specific files.

